# Text Overflowing Div

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to build a simple div with a span of text inside of it.

```
    <div id="bottom-text">
        <span>ONE STOP</span>
    </div>
```

And here is the simple CSS styling I have in effect for "#bottom-text":

```
    #bottom-text{
        font-weight:700;
        font-size:50px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:auto;
        position:relative;
        padding-top:25px;
        height:65px;
        width:auto;
    }
```

For some reason, the text "ONE STOP" displays partially outside of #bottom-text. (only the top portion of all the letters...) I've tried using padding to fix it but the text then overflows partially into the padding region!

Can anyone help me figure out why this text is displaying outside the div it is supposed to be contained within? (I've been testing Chrome and Firefox)

Thanks all.

Comment: Looks fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zYFfL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at your code, the `#bottom-text` is 65px height, the `font-size` is 50px, and `padding-top` is 25px

65-(50+25) = -10
So you will see only the top 10 pixel of your text.

Set `padding-top` to a lesser amount, and play with just so it is correct

Comment: I tried changing it all but it still seems to overflow? It seems like the span is ignoring the div container it is in entirely. Its weird actually it is working fine when I test it in Dreamweaver. Maybe there is just a bug or something, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Actually padding adds to the height of element, so #bottom-text is 65+25 (90px) high. I'd say line-height might have something to do with the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
.largefont {
   color: #0066FF;
   font-family:arial;
   font-size: 6px;
   display: inline;
} 

<span class="largefont">block level span</span>
```

Assign a class to the `span` and play with that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your line-height. Only thing I can think of is you might have some styles elsewhere that are adding some in. Try adding "line-height: 1;" to your existing #bottom-text CSS so that your text is actually 50px high. Or, if you want the text to vertically center in #bottom-text make your line-height match the height of #bottom-text (65px).